# Ordering VSI with the LAMP stack via slcli

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there a way to order the LAMP version of a VSI using `slcli`? I tried querying for a public image to use but do not see one listed

```
» slcli image list --public | grep -i lamp
162452   Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 LTS w/Docker (64-bit LAMP)                                      SYSTEM        PUBLIC  299743
241152   CentOS6.0-64-LAMP-CLOUD-INIT                                                        SYSTEM        PUBLIC  317028
469927   Public CentOS - with LAMP (test)                                                    SYSTEM        PUBLIC  475145
660781   HG-UbuntuLamp                                                                       SYSTEM        PUBLIC  278059
767597   LAMP-DEMO-handson
```

Worse comes to worse I can always deploy a LAMP VSI from the portal and make an image from that, but wanted to know if this worked out of the box on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

the slcli uses the method : http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions
to retrieve the valid list of OS, currently this method is not returning the LAMP OSs that's why you cannot order those VSIs using the slcli, as workaround you can create your own image template which contains the LAMP OS and use that image template to order new VSIs

Regards